# can't link with a main executable file

Tags: xcode6

Changed my deployment target to from 8.0 to 7.0.

Using Xcode 6 with latest iOS8 as base sdk. Getting this error when building for iOS7.1 device:

ld: can't link with a main executable file '/Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Clumsy_Bird-gotvuaeuyvrkzvfqpzsuxpmifimu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Clumsy Bird.app/Clumsy Bird' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue when building on Xcode 6 for an iPad. I was able to workaround this by visiting the "Edit Scheme" panel for my target, selecting the "Build" category, and unchecking the "Run" checkbox for my unit test target.

Comment: Thx Craig Otis... I'll try it next time... Manage to fix it by deleting the "test" target...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

1. Click your project in Navigator.
2. Select your **test** target. Switch to **general** tab if not there.
3. Select your application name from **Host Application** dropdown.

[image]

Comment: What was the need for Apple to do like this? I am completely frustrated with the XCode settings change. I have resolved the problem after i googled it and got the above solution.

Comment: In my case, this happened when I renamed the product; this solved it immediately :)

Comment: Hi Evgenii and all, I have a binary file that I generated by compiling C++ console program. When I am running it using terminal, it runs fine. When I am running it using NSTask in Xcode, I am getting error ld: can't link with a main executable file. Code:     NSTask *terminalOperation = [[NSTask alloc] init];
        terminalOperation.launchPath =  @"/usr/bin/g++";
        NSArray *argumentsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:filePath, nil];
        [terminalOperation setArguments:argumentsArray];
        [terminalOperation launch];
        [terminalOperation waitUntilExit];  Can you please help

Comment: This is still, believe it or not, a problem in Xcode 7. Apple: I'm not upset, just disappointed.

Answer (score 27):

I had a mismatch in values between on "Build Active Architecture Only" which was "Yes" for my test app, but "No" for my unit test target. Make sure these values are identical.

Comment: Worked for me , thnx

Comment: I second this. Huge time saver. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Build settings > IOS deployment target Make sure these values are identical in app and test app targets. Works for me.
[screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzZrg.png)

Comment: Bingo! Make sure version number matches

Answer (score 10):

I followed steps provided by "Evgeny" above, but my project build only when I unchecked "Allow testing Host Application APIs".
Thanks "Evgeny"!

Comment: This solution worked for me running XCode 9.4.1 using React Native