# Linker Command Failed: Cannot link with a main executable file for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I am having issues running my application on different devices via XCode.  If I test with my iPhone, which is running iOS 9.0.2, it runs fine.  However, when I run on iPads running anything between 7.0.4 and 8.4, I get the error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
ld: can't link with a main executable file '/Users/ttseng/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spin-alycjhujfjocfeaggybdmvitcjxx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/spin.app/spin' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My iOS Deployment Target is iOS 7.0.

How do I resolve this issue?

Things I've tried based on other posts I've seen on StackOverflow:

1. Ensured there are no duplicate implementation files listed under Build Phases > Compile Sources
2. Ensure there are no missing implementation files from Build Phases > Compile Sources
3. Clean Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the tests that were automatically generated when I created the app.  I had to follow the directions here after selecting my test target:

[can't link with a main executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031932/cant-link-with-a-main-executable-file)