# iOS - can't link with a main executable file (release)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated XCode to V 11.1, and since updating, for some reason when I run my app in release mode, I'm thrown the following error:

> ld: can't link with a main executable file
>   '/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp'
>   for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have absolutely no clue how to resolve this - and I can't run my app in release mode without it (and yes, I'm using a Distribution profile). Help would be much appreciated. I've browsed a few other answers but none seem to solve this issue.

When I navigate to that file path, 'myapp' is simply an icon with a circle and a slash through it (can't be a good sign). This same thing occurs even after I clean the build folder. When I try to rebuild in release mode, the build fails and throws me the above yet again.

**See full error:**

> Ld
>   /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/myappTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/myappTests
>   normal armv7 (in target 'myappTests' from project 'myapp')
>       cd /Users/admin/Desktop/myapp
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -target armv7-apple-ios8.4 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -F/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks -F/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks -F/Users/admin/Desktop/myapp/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/lib
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/myappTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myappTests.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp
>   -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/myappTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myappTests_lto.o
>   -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework Accelerate -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework GLKit -framework ImageIO -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework XCTest
>   -lPods-myappTests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/myappTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myappTests_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myapp.build/Release-iphoneos/myappTests.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Binary/myappTests
>
> ld: can't link with a main executable file
>   '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-btokobigvkxtgwgcjrapocxlexno/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app/myapp'
>   for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Post the full linker command invocation and error message (in the build tab click the lined icon on the right to expand the build command).

Comment: @trojanfoe see full error message above

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031932/cant-link-with-a-main-executable-file

Comment: Actually what I would do first is change the bundle id and see if that fixes it. If it does, try changing it back. :)

Comment: The stack link answer did not resolve it for me (I already have the accepted answer's mentioned box checked) - tried the bundle ID change. No dice :/ @matt

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally found the fix in my case. Hopefully this answer is helpful to others.

> Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme, and then tap the 'Build' category on
>   the left hand side.
>
> Under your appTests targets, uncheck "Run".

Problem solved.

Comment: It worked for me too. Any idea why this solution works? Adding an explanation here would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Could you say where do you find the slashed icon - it may be a sign Xcode tries to look at a wrong path. You may easily verify it with right-click on the project from Project Navigator, show in Finder. 
 
I recommend Changing deployment target to 8.4. 
 
A solution might be going to `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme`, choose Build and uncheck 'Run'

Comment: Very speculative answer.

Comment: I already have 'Allow testing Host Application APIs' checked :/

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the `ld: can't link with a main executable file` error because the `Build Settings` between my app target and the test app were different, mainly the iOS Deployment Target.

Ensuring that these two were the same allowed the build to succeed.

Comment: what setting in particular?